# maximize image size in email to suit all screen

Tags: image, outlook, image-resizing

I have problems as always when I add images in outlook.  The image looks ok on my own screen (using Lenovo X1 carbon).  However, when receivers use surface pro to read my messages, the images become very small.  How can I maximize my images to suit all screen resolution?  Thanks.

Comment: can anyone help as I need to send another email with a lot of images very soon?  Please help.